# Assign Role to the same security id with ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM templates that assigns the "Reader" RBAC roles to a security group on the ResourceGroup level. If I deploy the template once, it works, however if I rerun the template, it then throws this error

```
Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated.  (Code: RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted)
```

The code to the template is shown below

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string",
            
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The security group ID to assign the role to"
            }
        },
          "storageName" : {
          "type" : "string",
          
          "metadata" : {
            "description" : "Name of the Storage Name"
          }
        },

     
          "Tag" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "defaultValue" : "azure-cloud-shell",
            "metadata" : {
              "description" : "Tag name for the Azure Cloud Shell"
            }
          }

          

    },
    "variables": {
        
        "Contributor": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
        "guidUnique": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name)]"
        
        
         
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
            "tags" :{
               "ms-resource-usage" : "[parameters('Tag')]"
              
            },

            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_ZRS"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
               "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2"
              
            }
        },
         {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('storageName'), '/default')]",
         "type":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
         "apiVersion":"2018-07-01",
         "properties":{
            "deleteRetentionPolicy":{
               "enabled":true,
               "days":7
            }
         },
         "dependsOn":[
            "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageName'))]"
         ]
      },
        
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[guid('roleassingnment', variables('guidUnique'))]",
            "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', '/', parameters('storageName'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('storageName')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('Contributor')]",
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
            }
        },
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(guid(resourceGroup().id, parameters('storageName')))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7')]",
                
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
            }
        }
        
    ]
}
```

It appears that ARM template assignment of roles to security is not idempotent.

Please kindly advise

Comment: In normal we cannot update our role assignment with the same name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Role Assignment Update are not permitted. Make sure you pass a unique GUID for every new role assignment. For more details, please refer to [here](https://jasonmasten.com/2021/04/13/tenant-id-application-id-principal-id-and-scope-are-not-allowed-to-be-updated/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afc10f35-fa20-467e-b927-aeefdbf35eaf/arm-microsoftstoragestorageaccountsprovidersroleassignments-roleassignmentupdatenotpermitted?forum=azurescripting)

Comment: This isn't an update, its running the same ARM template multiple times. ARM is supposed to be idempotent, so this is a massive bug.